# How to minimize a function without using a loop

Tags: matlab, function, minimization

I have a function (ExpSemivariance) that creates a vector of 11 elements. This elements are then represented on a graph in a scattered diagram and I intend finding the curve (Theoretical) that best fit 'ExpSemivariance' by using mimimum residual (in this case, but any other minimization function can be used)

```
Nug = 5;
Sill = 7899;
alpha = 1.7;

Step = 10;
q = 11;

      for i=1:q
          Theoretical(i,1) = Nug+Sill*(1-exp(-(Lag(i,1)/R)^alpha));
      end
      Error = sum(abs(Theoretical-ExpSemivariance));
      while Step > 1
          R = R + Step;
          for i=1:q
              Theoretical(i,1) = Nug+Sill*(1-exp(-(Lag(i,1)/R)^alpha));
          end
          error = sum(abs(Theoretical-ExpSemivariance));
          if error > Error
              R = R - Step;
              Step = Step/2;
          else
              Error = error;
          end
      end
```

With the only variable being 'R', the script above Works quite well.

The problem is, i am assuming alpha is 1.7. But I actually need to find the correct value of alpha (ranging from 1:2, steps 0.1) and R (ranging from 1-4000) simultaneously which best minimizes the minimizes the error (between ExpSemivariance and Theoretical). Is there an appropriate way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you best look into [mathematical optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization), because I have the impression you are trying to re-invent the wheel a bit (e.g. the `sum(abs(x))` is a lot less common than e.g. `sum(x.^2)` in optimization since the latter is quite a bit easier to solve since the derivatives of the latter are easy to compute; also, the way you choose `step` seems a bit uncommon to me).

In MATLAB, if you have the optimization toolbox, many of the relevant algorithms are already implemented for you. They are a reliable way to get good results (unless you want perfect control of the optimization algorithm you use), such that you don't have to roll your own algorithms (which are probably not as reliable). Also, if you look around on the internet, I'm quite positive you should be able to find free implementations that have similar functionality.

### Approach 1: discrete grids / brute force

If what you want, is really to minimize that misfit between your function and data for some discrete values of `R = {1, ..., 4000}` and `alpha = {1, 1.1, ..., 2}`, then I would either use a `for` loop over all those variables or use vectorization to possibly speed this up.

```
% still requires Lag, ExpSemivariance
Nug   = 5;
Sill  = 7899;

model = @(R, alpha) Nug + Sill .* ( 1 - exp(-(Lag./R).^alpha));
cost  = @(R, alpha) sum(abs(model(R, alpha) - ExpSemivariance));

R     = 1:4000;
alpha = 1:0.1:2;

% this creates matrices (RR, alphaalpha) for all combinations of values (R, alpha)
[RR, alphaalpha] = ndgrid(R, alpha);

% now evaluate it over the complete grid of combinations
error = arrayfun(cost, RR, alphaalpha);

errorMin   = min(error(:));         % compute the minimum
idxMinimum = find(error==errorMin); % find it in your results
RMin       = RR(idxMinimum);
alphaMin   = alphaalpha(idxMinimum);

% since this is 2D, you can still visualize this:
figure;
mesh(R, alpha, error); hold all;
plot3(RMin, alphaMin, errorMin, '.k')
xlabel('R');
ylabel('alpha');
zlabel('error');
```

Certainly, there are better algorithms (but I'm not familiar enough with them; all that I know is that it's in general quite a hard problem).
Also, note that my approach is very brute-force and hence scales quite poorly: adding more variables, or scanning over a finer grid will quickly exhaust your computer's resources. If that's the case, it really pays off to gradually scan the grid, or use multiple for loops where you keep track of the best value seen so far.

### Approach 2: continuous variables / optimization based

This is the more common problem in optimization (and, I think, also the problem you are trying to solve). It assumes that `R` and `alpha` are real values (so can take any value, possibly within a certain range), such that you can let an optimization algorithm do the looping for you to determine the values that minimize the objective function.

In your case, if you are sure about those ranges of `R` and `alpha`, I would look into the `fmincon` function. From the top of my head (i.e. no guarantees the code works), I think you should be able to call it as:

```
% still requires Lag, ExpSemivariance
Nug  = 5;
Sill = 7899;

R     = [1 10  4000]; % minimum, initial guess, maximum
alpha = [1 1.7 2   ]; % minimum, initial guess, maximum
theta = [R; alpha];   % parameter vector for optimization toolbox
thetaMin  = theta(:,1);
thetaMax  = theta(:,3);
thetaInit = theta(:,2);

model     = @(R, alpha) Nug + Sill .* ( 1 - exp(-(Lag./R).^alpha));
error     = @(R, alpha) sum(abs(model(R, alpha) - ExpSemivariance));
objective = @(theta) error(theta(1), theta(2));

% execute "help fmincon"/"doc fmincon" for more information about this
thetaOpt = fmincon(objective, thetaInit, [], [], [], [], thetaMin, thetaMax);
RMin     = thetaOpt(1)
alphaMin = thetaOpt(2)
```

This approach generalizes quite well to more variables and to bigger ranges (in fact, even infinite ranges are feasible with this approach).

The actual looping happens within `fmincon` that uses well-tested algorithms to determine what steps it should take to improve your fit. It is not completely foolproof, as having good initial values makes it a lot more likely to obtain better values of your `R` and `alpha` in a shorter amount of time. But to learn the in-and-outs, you should really look into the theory of optimization and/or the documentation of the optimization toolbox. If you are getting poor results, I would recommend to first try changing `abs(x)` to `(x).^2` as that is a lot easier for most optimization algorithms.